# Pandas filtering based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I'm new to Pandas and Python, so I maybe have very trivial question.

I have Data frame like this:

```
                       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
0                5_TKE12  0  1  0  0  2  0  1  0  0  0  0
1              1_aeroD15  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0
2                    6D9  1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
3               24_RSG24  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
4     Other imm.as_SHF12  0  1  1  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
...                  ... .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
2078               45E72  0  0  2  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2079            23_TKC61  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2080          14_aeroD10  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
2081            16_TKD11  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
2082    Sensativite_SHF6  0  2  2  2  2  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

I need to filter last column (#11) if value = 1, and I need to have first column(#0) as the result
So, I'll have `6D9` based on my example.

I tried to filter data frame but it hasn't helped.

---

I tried this:

```
filtered_ind = [1]
R4 = R4[:,R4[11].isin(filtered_ind)] #R4 is data Frame for table I showed above
print(R4)
```

I got this answer:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...  
2078    False
2079    False
2080    False
2081    False
2082    False
Name: 11, Length: 2083, dtype: bool)' is an invalid key
```

Comment: `df.loc[df[11] == 1, 0]`.

Comment: Assuming that you want to check against multiple values in column `11` using `filtered_ind`, the smallest change to make your code work is: `R4.loc[R4[11].isin(filtered_ind), 0]`, per @00's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was in the very beginning:

I should have used string "1":

```
filtered_ind = ['1'] #in my previous code was [1] :(
## and after that I used one of suggested answers:
R4 = R4.loc[R4[11].isin(filtered_ind), 0]
```

Thanks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter like:

```
df[0][df[11]==1]
```

Will give first column value when #11 is one

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it didn't help: I had the same table :(

Comment: Can you please share desired output? Because according to your example this solution gives the ```69D``` Do you want to change table? This line won't change the table if you want you can assign it to another variable.

Comment: I added filter as you've advised:
R4[0][R4[11]==1]

and I got this:

Series([], Name: 0, dtype: object)



As a result I need values from column 0 if it's 1 in column 11

Comment: Then it means there is no 1 in your 11th column.

Comment: It's not possible. I know that there are values "1"
I've checked column 10 for "1" values (there are a lot of values "1", info 100%). Result is the same

Comment: Then you need to filter column number 10 not 11

Comment: I´ve tried this answer and it works:
df['0'][df['11']==1]
Maybe the problem is the column name, you need to pass it like string instead int

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it useful.